# WKWebView is not working with FileManager for documentDirectory

Tags: swift, wkwebview

Here is my code:

```
var fileContent = ""
let baseURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let fileURL = baseURL.appendingPathComponent("index").appendingPathExtension("html")
do {
    fileContent = try String(contentsOf: fileURL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed getting content of the file: \(fileURL), Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    fileContent = ""
}

editorWebView!.loadHTMLString(fileContent, baseURL: baseURL)
```

Problem is that:

```
<img src='resources/check-box-uncheck.png'>
```

WKWebView load html string but do not display images. I have copied the index.html file and related files in documentDirectory using FileManager. I don't want to use mainBundle.
Please any help?

baseURL is: 
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/C89D5B66-30FD-4B88-949F-F591E0EA1BE7/Documents/

Function to check files and folders:
func allFilesList(atPath: URL) -> [String]? {

```
    var allFileNames = [String]()
    do {
        let fullPaths = try self.contentsOfDirectory(at: atPath, includingPropertiesForKeys:[], options: FileManager.DirectoryEnumerationOptions.skipsHiddenFiles)
        for fileName in fullPaths {
            let theFileName = fileName.lastPathComponent
            allFileNames.append(theFileName)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print("Error for list folders OR notes: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    return allFileNames
}
```

Comment: did you implement the delegate protocol? One of the methods in there controls where and what can load.

Comment: @Mgetz Yes, I did. editorWebView!.uiDelegate = self and included at class WKUIDelegate

Comment: @matt I have method to check file are in place.

Comment: @matt please check method I have added.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug in my code. I didn't append the files to copy.

```
let fileURL = urlPath.appendingPathComponent("index").appendingPathExtension("html")
```

Adding above line resolved the problem.

Actual method I implemented is:

```
//To copy file in userDocuments
    func copyFileFromThisAppMainToUserDocument(fName: String, fExtension:String) -> Bool {
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let urlPath = fileManager.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let fileURL = urlPath.appendingPathComponent(fName).appendingPathExtension(fExtension)
        if let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fName, withExtension: fExtension) {
            // if file exist, copy it
            do {
                try fileManager.copyItem(at: bundleURL, to: fileURL)
                return true
            } catch let error as NSError { // Handle the error
                print("\(fName) copy failed! Error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
                return false
            }
        } else {
            print("\(fName) not exist in bundle folder")
            return false
        }
    }
```